# How do you implement a parser for a given intermediate representation tree grammar in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree

I have the following IRTree Grammar: 
(N* denotes 0, 1 or more repetitions of N)

```
IRSequence     IRTree*

IRTree         **MOVE(TEMP** id, IRExp)
               **MOVE(MEM**(IRExp), IRExp)
               **JUMP** id
               **CJUMP(**IRExp, Op, IRExp, id, id**)**
               **OUTPUT(**IRExp**)**
               **LABEL** id
               **SEQ(**IRTree, IRTree**)**

IRExp          **CONST** SIGNED_INT
               **BINOP(**IRExp, Op, IRExp**)**
               **TEMP** id
               **MEM(**IRExp**)**

Op             **LT|LE|EQ|ADD|SUB|MUL|DIV**
```

How would i go about implementing a parser for the above grammar. 
How would i build an AST?

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty big topic which requires quite a bit of studying and understanding before implementation. The way I'd recommend going about tacking this would be using parser/lexer generators like [JFlex](http://jflex.de/manual.html#Example) and [cup](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/), for basic learning. Once you have a handle on that, you can move forward to other options such as [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) that can help with generating.

To begin, let's talk about the three basic steps to implementing a language - the first of which being a lexer.

This is where JFlex comes in with generating a lexer - a program that essentially reads an input file and determines patterns in the character sequence and assigns appropriate groups 'tokens' or essentially a little flag that the parser will use later on.

The second step is the parser - the part of the program that takes an input sequence of tokens from the lexer and then sorts them. This is where cup comes in handy - it can work with the lexer generated from JFlex and parse the tokens. A parser can have a few sections, but for now let's focus on the grammar section. With cup, I'd recommend translating your given grammar to a different form - something called [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) or [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form). Once you have that step done, you can move onto the next step of this problem, the Abstract Syntax Tree.

The AST is the action part of your parser; previously, your parser matched a sequence of tokens to an BNF/EBNF sequence defined in your grammar, but didn't do anything with it. When you have a matched sequence, you have the option to execute action code in CUP. Using this action code, you can form a tree - and there are several options to do this. Some people prefer to use a list, a doubly linked list, or a treemap to list a few options. The goal of the AST is to create a map structure that draws out your grammar and applies relations to sections in your grammar called terminals and non-terminals.

I've gotten a bit a head, so to explain briefly, a terminal is just what it sounds like - an ending point in your grammar. In your example, these would be your comparison operators (LT, GT, etc..). Likewise, non-terminals are points in your grammar that can be broken down into other non-terminals or terminals combined. An example would be the non-terminal starting point, IRSequence is a parent of the non-terminal IRTree, which can have some terminals, but is also the parent of a non-terminal IRExp, which can end in a terminal or include additinal non-terminals.

The final step in a language is compilation. But this seems to go beyond your question, so I'll leave it for now and expand upon it in an edit if requested.

Comment: If you're having further issues with specific aspects of what I've mentioned, please feel free to ask in the comments or message me directly.